# How long does it take to reinstall Ubuntu version 16.04

Tags: 16.04, reinstall

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04 my computer would not start. I decided to reinstall it. I chose reinstall option. It is now close to 24 hours. The re installation is at its first step "Removing conflicting operating system files"

Command window shows some processes, which suggests that reinstall is working. Does anybody know, how long this will take?

Is there a way to bypass this step?

Comment: Nuke system and reinstall. Easier.

Comment: I'm reinstalling but I want to preserve my work from previous version. Are you suggesting installing fresh and forget what I had in previous version?

Comment: @Bogan I am suggesting you backup everything you need on a flashdrive or external disk and do a clean install. I have never even noticied the re-install option you are alluding to but I couldn't expect it to work reliably. Too many edge cases.

Comment: Why upgrading in the first place? For me, a full backup takes 10 minutes, a fresh install takes 20 minutes, a full upgrade takes 2+ hours. Better keep your work on a separate partition, it will not be affected by upgrades or by changing the OS.

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting you backup everything you need on a flashdrive or external disk and do a clean install. I have never even noticied the re-install option you are alluding to but I couldn't expect it to work reliably. Too many edge cases.